# Can I have two separate minecraft apps on my sole account?

Tags: applications

I have my own device and my two kids have a tablet each linked to my Amazon account (kid profiles). They both want minecraft but want to have their own worlds, I.e. Not share. Can this be done?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you don't want to spend any money buying minecraft you have an option (only if the devices run android) to get apks using the internet which you don't have to pay and you can update them on that site personally I use aptoide

Comment: You mean *do piracy*, in short. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the two devices will have independent data and a single purchase of an app can be installed on multiple devices with the same account. If they want to play multiplayer they should make sure not to sign into the same Minecraft account (not sure how that works on the pocket version) and single player will just work.